# Report Builder 3.0 SWITCH expression DEFAULT/ELSE

Tags: reporting-services, expression, reporting, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-expression

I am trying to display a different logo based on the users franchise number.

Parameter = UserFranNr

If the value <> 99 and <> 87, then the embedded image to display is ID0. (Embedded image names are strings.)

This works with nested IIFs but seems to be the right time/place to use `SWITCH`.

(There is a strong possibility that more franchises will use their own logo in future.)

```
=Switch 
(
Parameters!UserFranNr.Value = "99","ID99",
Parameters!UserFranNr.Value = "87","ID87",
"ID0"
)
```

I have not found any documentation that explains how to implement a default value using `SWITCH`.

Is this even possible? If so how? If not any decent alternatives?
Thanks

Resources:
[Expression Examples (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx)
[Define Formula Dialog Box (Report Builder)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240820.aspx)

Plus here and other forums.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

There is no default clause in the SSRS `Switch` expression.

However, you can always modify your expression slightly:

```
=Switch 
(
  Parameters!UserFranNr.Value = "99","ID99",
  Parameters!UserFranNr.Value = "87","ID87",
  true, "ID0"
)
```

Since any time the last condition is hit it will be explicitly evaluated to `true`, the last row will effectively act as a default value.

I've used this in the past without issues. Other than perhaps generating frowns in people who read the expression, it works perfectly well with minimal effort.

As to whether it's sensible behaviour to have no default clause, well, that's a question for Microsoft. It certainly seems odd to me, but there you go.

Comment: The real question is what kind of unskilled wit tought it was a good idea to implement switch operator without an explicit DEFAULT case, since it's decades that switch it's working like this flawlessly.

Microsoft have always suprirses.